# ADF table refresh issue

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I am facing an issue in ADF table.
When i click on editable cell, table executes and i lose focus on cell, focus goes to first cell in header.

[image]

Table properties:

```
<af:table value="#{bindings.RgcResultsMonitor1.collectionModel}" var="row"
                  rows="#{bindings.RgcResultsMonitor1.rangeSize}"
                  emptyText="#{bindings.RgcResultsMonitor1.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                  rowBandingInterval="0"
                  selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.RgcResultsMonitor1.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                  selectionListener="#{bindings.RgcResultsMonitor1.collectionModel.makeCurrent}" fetchSize="#{bindings.RgcResultsMonitor1.rangeSize}" id="t2"
                  contentDelivery="immediate"
                  rowSelection="single">
```

any advice ?

Comment: any help here please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing setting ChangeEventPolicy="none" of the page iterator in the page definition file.

http://andrejusb.blogspot.be/2017/02/adf-editable-table-recommendation-for.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ChangeEventPolicy as Stooge suggested and if it doesn't work then check that is there any code written in getter method of variables in bean or in rowImpl class of viewObjects
Are you executing table viewObject in bean ?